# How to pass a variant as constructor parameter or as function argument

Tags: c++, variant

I am reading about implementation of state machines using variants. I try to create a construction that take a variant parameter to initialize the state. However whent the constructor is defined , I get a warning that this is  recognized as function declaration.

Moreover when I try to define a setter for the state, compiler error is generated when try to call this

Here is the code

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <cassert>

struct DoorState
{
    struct DoorOpened {};
    struct DoorClosed {};
    struct DoorLocked {};

    using State = std::variant<DoorOpened, DoorClosed, DoorLocked>;
    DoorState()
    {
    }
    DoorState(State & state)
    {
        m_state = state;
    }
    void open()
    {
        m_state = std::visit(OpenEvent{}, m_state);
    }

    void close()
    {
        m_state = std::visit(CloseEvent{}, m_state);
    }

    void lock()
    {
        m_state = std::visit(LockEvent{}, m_state);
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        m_state = std::visit(UnlockEvent{}, m_state);
    }

    struct OpenEvent
    {
        State operator()(const DoorOpened&) { return DoorOpened(); }
        State operator()(const DoorClosed&) { return DoorOpened(); }
        // cannot open locked doors
        State operator()(const DoorLocked&) { return DoorLocked(); }
    };

    struct CloseEvent
    {
        State operator()(const DoorOpened&) { return DoorClosed(); }
        State operator()(const DoorClosed&) { return DoorClosed(); }
        State operator()(const DoorLocked&) { return DoorLocked(); }
    };

    struct LockEvent
    {
        // cannot lock opened doors
        State operator()(const DoorOpened&) 
        { 
            std::cout << "DoorOpened" << std::endl;
            return DoorOpened(); 
        }
        State operator()(const DoorClosed&) { return DoorLocked(); }
        State operator()(const DoorLocked&) { return DoorLocked(); }
    };

    struct UnlockEvent
    {
        // cannot unlock opened doors
        State operator()(const DoorOpened&) { return DoorOpened(); }
        State operator()(const DoorClosed&) { return DoorClosed(); }
        // unlock
        State operator()(const DoorLocked&) { return DoorClosed(); }
    };
    void set(State state)
    {
    }
    State m_state;
};

int main()
{
    //DoorState s(DoorState::DoorOpened);
    DoorState s; 
    s.set(DoorState::DoorOpened);
    s.lock();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `DoorState s((DoorState::DoorOpened));` or `DoorState s{DoorState::DoorOpened};` instead? (These are the usual tricks in this case.) ([SO: Avoid the most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13249766/7478597))

Comment: Without vexing parse, it would be `DoorState s(DoorState::DoorOpened());` (as state in answer, you need instance but you only provide type) but because of vexing parse, you have to use alternative as  `DoorState s{DoorState::DoorOpened{}};`

Comment: `compiler error is generated` It might be helpful to know what that error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
s.set(DoorState::DoorOpened);
```

you are passing a type, you should pass an instance of a type, try

```
s.set(DoorState::DoorOpened{});
```

after this change I was able to compile in MSVC 2019 (16.1.3)

Edit: This is an edit to address Scheff and Jarod24 comments, there would have been a case of most vexing parse if we were to uncomment the constructor and write

```
DoorState s(DoorState::DoorOpened());
```

This could have been fixed using the uniform initialization syntax, see e.g.
https://arne-mertz.de/2015/07/new-c-features-uniform-initialization-and-initializer_list/

```
DoorState s{DoorState::DoorOpened{}};
```

This would have solved the most vexing parse issue but created a new issue: `DoorState::DoorOpened{}`would have been a temporary and it could have never been bound to the input argument of the ctor:

```
DoorState(State& state)
```

we then would have needed to change it to

```
DoorState(const State& state)
```

Thanks again to Jarod and Scheff for pointing out the issue.

Comment: @Scheff,  I tried both of them but no one works. It is very strange. Only the call of the set "s.set(DoorState::DoorOpened{});" works

Comment: @getsoubl , which compiler are you using? I tried with MSVC and it works, take a look at https://godbolt.org/z/SjxSt8  for clang and let me know

Comment: I am using the VS 2017 compiler. The toolset that is used is the Visual Studio 2017 (v141)

Comment: @getsoubl, I am not Scheff, I think that Scheff got confused with another very similar issue: the most vexing parse. Your issue was NOT a most vexing parse issue, it was simply that you were passing a type instead of an instance of a type

Comment: If OP has fixed the issue in the commented code, OP would have most vexing parse.

Comment: @Jarod42 correct, looks like that I misunderstood Scheff all along. I did not even see the commented out part.